# Regex to check if a string has only spaces

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want a regular expression to check if a string has only spaces.

Example: " "

I'm currently using this regex

```
[/^ *$/]
```

But it's also detecting a string which has words in it.

Example: "abc xyz"

I want to use this regex in a postgresql function like following

```
IF r.colmn IS NULL  OR CAST(r.colmn as text) = '' 
       OR CAST(r.colmn as text) ~ '[/^ *$/]' -- regex not working
THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'Do something';       
END IF;
```

Is there any regex I can use in a postgresql function which only checks for a string with only spaces?

Comment: I don't see why a regex would be necessary. `if trim(r.colmn) = ''` will do the same thing. And probably more efficient as well

Comment: i do agree with @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm new to postgresql and since you're suggesting trim() is more efficient, I'll use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `[/` and `/]` from your regex:

```
IF r.colmn IS NULL  OR CAST(r.colmn as text) = '' 
       OR CAST(r.colmn as text) ~ '^ *$'
THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'Do something';       
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working and the website says I could only accept your answer after 10 minutes. Could you explain why I need to remove those?

Comment: It needs to be removed because Postgres regex doesn't require any delimiters like PHP does and using `[` and `]` makes your regex invalid as characters inside `[` and `]` are interpreted as character class.

Comment: What will the regex if I want to test if my string contains both `empty spaces` and `new line characters` and nothing else ?

Comment: @UsamaTahir `'^\s*$'`, where `\s` matches any whitespace including `new line`. if you only want `space` and `newline` you could do `'^[ \n]*$'`, but keep in mind that in a Windows environment you may also need `'^[ \n\r]*$'`, and what if you want to capture tabs, etc. I would recommend the `\s` solution. https://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

For instance to find non-empty notes:

```sql
SELECT "notes".*
FROM "notes"
WHERE
  "notes"."body" IS NOT NULL
  AND
  NOT (body ~* '^\s*$')
```